# Restricting team user level access to edit backlog boards in visual studio online

Tags: agile, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, scrumboard

How can we restrict access to edit/move backlog boards in VSO from one section/column(New/Committed/Developed/Done) to another section/column(New/Committed/Developed/Done).

we are facing issues as there is no control on board movement for our project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move backlogs from one section to another section on the Backlog Board, one needs to have the **Edit work items in this node** permission for the Area and Iteration path. You can deny the permission to disable the ability for that specific engineer.

Go to the team project admin page (https://vsoaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/teamprojectname/_admin/_areas), right click the Area and select Security. Select the engineer you would like to set the permission to set disable that permission. See:

[image]

Per my above screenshot, user Victory Song can't move work items which is under Agile area. (and she can't edit work items under Agile area either.)